# How to join Caliburn.Micro with Spring.net

Tags: .net, caliburn.micro, spring.net

How to create a Caliburn.Micro app using Spring.net? I found tutorials about Caliburn together with Spring.net but not together with Caliburn.Micro. What is the starting point? How to define the app and having the configuration in Spring?

Comment: If it isn't immediately obvious how you would you use both in your application, perhaps you don't need both?

Comment: Caliburn has a bootstrapper and a simple IoC. I didn't found a way to integrate the spring IoC instead of the simple one brought with Caliburn.

Comment: To use a different IOC framework, you can implement your own custom `Bootstrapper` derived class, which locates services using your desired framework.

Comment: ... thought there are already existing solutions and don't want to reinvent the wheel... it seems I can't find one and I have to code it myself. ;-)